# How to connect a Motorola Xoom 2 ME (MZ607) on fastboot mode to a PC?

Tags: fastboot, usb-drivers, android-sdk, motorola-xoom

I am trying to connect a Motorola Xoom 2 ME (MZ607) on fastboot mode to my laptop running Windows 10 as per described here:

https://goo.gl/ln57PX

When the system loads, Windows recognizes the device. Not on fastboot, though. Motorola usb drivers and Android SDK are installed and updated.

Is this normal? If not, how to solve?

Comment: The motorola website behind the link expects me to sign in to access the resource. Consider providing an alternative way to access the resource without the need of user credentials.

Comment: Actually, the issue I attempted to describe, and get help with, was the issue of fastboot oem get_unlock_data on the device (tablet) on fastboot mode.  After posting this question I realized that if I try fastboot devices, it gets listed.

Comment: Consider self-answering the question in that case.

Comment: I tried reaching out for Motorola live chat and they said my device isn't unlockable... So, tough luck!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the issue I attempted to describe, and get help with, was the issue of fastboot oem get_unlock_data on the device (tablet) on fastboot mode. After posting this question I realized that if I try fastboot devices, it gets listed.